# Перенос данных по условию в Google sheets

Tags: скрипт, макросы

Поступила рабочая задача написать макрос по переносу данных в таблице, требуется переносить данные из строки таблицы по условию в колонке статус. Если я выставляю в колонке статус значение "В серверную 2" то данные из колонки "Корпус (название модели)" и "Корпус (инвентарный номер)" должны вырезаться Ctrl + X и вставиться в лист "серверная 2 этаж" Подскажите решение, записывая макрос не выходит применять его по статусу в выпадающем списке, смог только назначить скрипт на картинку.

```
    function SERVERNAYA1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5:E5').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Серверная 2 этаж'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('C5:D5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Второй этаж\'!D5:E5').moveTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange());
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Данные Ok');
  spreadsheet.getRange('5:5').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('A4'));
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H7').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Второй этаж'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

[image: Таблица Второй этаж]

[image: Серверная 2]